# How I make a SCHTASKS job to run everyday except saturday and sunday?

Tags: windows, windows-task-scheduler

I wrote a script in Ruby, and I want to run that script with SCHTASKS command in everyday except saturday and sunday. How do I solve this problem?

PS:: crontab on linux easier than schtasks on windows -_-"

Answer (score 0):

Use /XML parameter.

> schtasks /Create /Xml sample.xml /TN taskname

XML is easy to make once you create a task manually, and export it.
XML Sample:

```
  ...
  <Triggers>
    <CalendarTrigger>
      <StartBoundary>2013-03-19T03:00:00</StartBoundary>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      <ScheduleByWeek>
        <DaysOfWeek>
          <Monday />
          <Tuesday />
          <Wednesday />
          <Thursday />
          <Friday />
        </DaysOfWeek>
        <WeeksInterval>1</WeeksInterval>
      </ScheduleByWeek>
    </CalendarTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  ...
```